# import custom javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How to import https://anseki.github.io/plain-draggable/ in angular ?

I've `npm i plain-draggable` then import in angular.json the .min.js

In html

```
  <span id="draggable" style="background-color: lightskyblue;">adipiscing</span>
  elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
  enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
  aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

And in component :
`declare const PlainDraggable: any;`

then called in constructor `PlainDraggable()`

I get the error `Cannot call a class as a function`

Comment: `new PlainDraggable()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling it on your constructor, try calling it on your AfterViewInit hook like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const draggable = new PlainDraggable(document.getElementById('draggable'));
}
```